# Ways to prevent dying when a tree explodes/how to prevent a tree from exploding

Tags: mother-3

In Mother 2 (Earthbound), when a tree blows up my guts save me and I'm left with 1 hp. In the earlier part of Mother 3, there are many trees that I have to fight. They all seem to blow up when killed, too, and I save myself by getting to the "You Win" part. What are some ways to survive the blowing up of trees other than this? Are there ways to prevent trees from blowing up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From memory, the trees (Territorial Oaks) explode/blow up whenever you defeat them. My advice would be avoid them (i.e., **run away** from battle). It may take a few attempts, but it's better than trying to fight it directly and risk them bursting into flame and KO'ing you.